# Not getting any row data from database using c# asp.net.

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3-tier

I can not get any row data from database using c# asp.net.I am trying to fetch one row  data from my DB but it is not returning any row.I am using 3-tire architecture for this and i am explaining my code below.

> index.aspx.cs:

```
protected void userLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (loginemail.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && loginpass.Text.Trim().Length >= 6)
            {
                objUserBO.email_id = loginemail.Text.Trim();
                objUserBO.password = loginpass.Text.Trim();
                DataTable dt= objUserBL.getUserDetails(objUserBO);
                Response.Write(dt.Rows.Count);
            }
        }
```

> userBL.cs:

```
 public DataTable getUserDetails(userBO objUserBO)
        {
           userDL objUserDL = new userDL();
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = objUserDL.getUserDetails(objUserBO);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

> userDL.cs:

```
public DataTable getUserDetails(userBO objUserBO)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CmVar.convar);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string sql = "SELECT  * from T_User_Master WHERE User_Email_ID= ' " + objUserBO.email_id + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                SqlDataAdapter objadp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                objadp.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                return dt;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

When i am checking the output of `Response.Write(dt.Rows.Count);`,it is showing `0`.So please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: profile your db call, probably your trace will reveal the problem

Comment: First, a question - does `User_Email_ID` definitely store the email address?

Comment: @AdrianWragg:Yes I have field name `User_Email_ID` in my database.

Comment: Secondly, a warning. You are passing user-generated text straight through to a database call, and opening yourself up to SQL Injection attacks. A username of `'; drop table T_User_Master; --` could wipe out your users table.

Comment: @satya you should investigate the sql generated from your code so that you can understand the problem, for example what is the objUserBO.email_id? the sql string obtained is regular? objUserBO can be null? SQL Server profiler will help you to solve the problem

Comment: @Infer-On:yes,in `objUserBO.email_id` is not null it is containing the proper input inserted.

Comment: @satya please can you update your question with the detail of the query call to your db? what is exactly your db call and what your db respond?

Comment: @satya to figure out the exact problem i would say for time being comment out the where condition from your query. make it  string sql = "SELECT  * from T_User_Master"; and see if you are getting data. if yes then something with your passed value else any exception is there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your your query string has a redundant space between `'` and `"` mark. That might be causing all the trouble as your email gets space in front.

It is by all means better to add parameters to your query with use of [SqlConnection.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
string sql = "SELECT * from T_User_Master WHERE User_Email_ID=@userID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@userID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@userID"].Value = objUserBO.email_id;
```